# Cypress-cucumber-preprocessor for cypress baseball owner

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I previously used cypress-cucumber-preprocessor using this guideline -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor I understand that in place of install **npm install --save-dev cypress-cucumber-preprocessor** now I should use this guideline -> **https://www.npmjs.com/package/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor** implementing **npm install @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor**. Let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

is a fork of

https://github.com/Klaveness-Digital/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

which is a public, community-maintained edition which include also installation instructions.

You can read more on:
https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/689

Comment: Thanks for the answer; my question is, if you know does the badeball version will replace the cypress-cucumber-preprocessor version 4.3.1 ? Or is recommended to continue using the 4.3.1? I read that badeball will take the reins, but I am not pretty sure. The badeball version was written in typescript, and the documentation is not the best to start from scratch.

Comment: ther is a transfer of ownership to badeball, as the previouose package are stepping down so I suppose the badeball  is going to take reins in the future.